# Python text based game - inventory issues, now not prompting anything

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out where I went wrong in my text-based game. It runs through all the rooms no problem. However, it does not prompt or acknowledge the inventory piece of it. I have looked through a lot of the answers on here and tried a few different things which has made it worse, now it is just completing without prompting for anything *facepalm*
TIA!

Here is my current code for the main body of the game, like I mentioned above, it is now not prompting for anything:

```
def instructions():# to give instructions
    print("_____________________________________________________________________________")
    print("Welcome to the Queen Mary!")
    print("Navigate through the rooms on the Queen Mary, picking up items needed to rid the vessel of the final boss, Walter J Adamson, who is haunting Stateroom B340.")
    print("You are starting on the Top Deck and can select the commands: go North, go South, go East, or go West.")
    print("You have 6 items you must get in order to win, to add to inventory type 'get 'item name'")
    print("You may also exit the game at any point using the 'Quit' word.")
    print("Good luck!")
    print("_____________________________________________________________________________")
#to set up rooms
rooms = {'Top Deck': {'name': 'Top Deck', 'go South': 'Pool Room', 'go North': 'The Mauretania Room', 'go East': 'Hatch Door #13',
                        'text': 'You are on the Top Deck.'},
         'The Mauretania Room': {'name': 'The Mauretania Room', 'go East': 'Stateroom B340', 'go South': 'Top Deck', 'item': 'Priest',
                     'text': 'You entered The Mauretania Room.'},
         'Stateroom B340': {'name': 'Stateroom B340', 'go West': 'The Mauretania Room', 'item': 'Walter J Adamson',
                    'text': 'You entered Stateroom B340!'},
         'Pool Room': {'name': 'Pool Room', 'go West': 'Boiler Room #4', 'go North': 'Top Deck', 'go East': 'The Mayfair Room', 'item': 'Holy Robe',
                    'text': 'You entered the Pool Room.'},
         'Boiler Room #4': {'name': 'Boiler Room #4', 'go West': 'Pool Room', 'item': 'Holy Relic',
                    'text': 'You entered Boiler Room #4.'},
         'The Mayfair Room': {'name': 'The Mayfair Room', 'go West': 'Pool Room', 'item': 'Candles',
                    'text': 'You entered The Mayfair Room.'},
         'Hatch Door #13': {'name': 'Hatch Door #13', 'go West': 'Top Deck', 'go North': 'Bottom Deck', 'item': 'Salt',
                    'text': 'You entered Hatch Door #13.'},
         'Bottom Deck': {'name': 'Bottom Deck', 'go South': 'Hatch Door #13', 'item': 'Holy Bible',
                    'text': 'You entered the Bottom Deck.'}
}
#commands
inventory = ['Priest', 'Holy Bible', 'Salt', 'Candles', 'Holy Robe', 'Holy Relic']
directions = ['go North', 'go South', 'go East', 'go West']
Exit_command = 'Quit'
instructions()
#to set up game loop and inventory

def main():
    current_room = 'Top Deck'
    inventory = []

    def show_status():
        print('')
        print(f'You are currently at the {current_room}')
        print(f'You currently have:', *inventory, sep='-')
        if rooms[current_room]['item'] in inventory:
            print('There are no items here.')
        else:
            print(f'There is a ' + rooms[current_room]['item'])

    command = input('\nPlease enter a direction or take an item: \n').strip().lower()
    while True:
        show_status()
        current_item = rooms[current_room]['item']

        if command in directions:
            if command not in rooms[current_room]:
                print("Sorry, you can't go that way, please try again.")
                if current_room == 'Stateroom B340':
                    if len(inventory) != 7:
                        print("GAME OVER -  Walter J Adamson has possessed you!\U0001F47B")
                        break
                    else:
                        print("*Ghost Noises* \U0001F47B You have successfully rid the Queen Mary of Walter J Adamson’s ghost! Thank you for playing!")
                        break
        elif command == 'Quit':
            print('Bye!')
            break
        elif command == 'pick up {}'.format(current_item):
            if current_item not in inventory:
                print('You picked up the ' + current_item, 'and added it to your inventory.')
                inventory.append(current_item)
            elif current_item in inventory:
                print('You already have this item, do something else.')
            else:
                print('There is no item here.')
        else:
            print("That doesn't make sense, please try again.")
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question with a single, large code snippet, rather than multiple disjointed snippets? Currently, there is little context between the snippets, and the indentation is incorrect.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. I assume that at the start the inventory should be empty (which you accomplish by putting `inventory = []` at the start of the main function), but it seems that you want the actual inventory items (Priest, Holy Bible etc) to be associated to the rooms. If so then you should create a dictionary for this, like `rooms = {'Top Deck': {'item': 'Priest'}, 'Lower Deck': {'item': 'Holy Bible'}}` etc. From the rest of your code it seems this was there at some point, or at least it was planned. Can you explain that a bit more?

Comment: Also you should put `command = input(...)` _within_ the `while True` loop, otherwise it will just be called once.

Comment: @Marijn yes, that code is there, I will add it so you can see the full thing. The start of the game you have essentially 0 items in your inventory hence the inventory = [ ]

I originally had the command = input under the while True loop but it didn't fix the problem, so I thought I had it in the wrong spot. I have honestly tried numerous things and like I said feel like it got worse each time I tried to fix it lol its been very frustrating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. I have changed a few things:

- One important issue was transforming the input to lower case. This is a good idea because then the user can enter commands with or without lower case, however you compared commands against capitalized versions (for example `if command == 'Quit'` or 'go North' in the rooms dictionary etc) which can never be the same as `command.lower()`, which is 'quit', 'go north' etc. So I changed all comparison strings in the code to lower case as well.
- The `command = input()` line should be inside of the loop
- The Top Deck room should also have an `'item'` entry in the dictionary, even if it is just the empty string, because you assign that value to `current_item`. To prevent this showing up in the status description I added an extra condition for printing that there are no items.
- The final room check should be at the start of the loop and not inside of the directions check.
- Code for actually changing the room was missing, I added that as an `else` condition in the directions check.
- I removed the global lists `inventory` and `Exit_command` as they were not used.

Full code:

```
def instructions():# to give instructions
    print("_____________________________________________________________________________")
    print("Welcome to the Queen Mary!")
    print("Navigate through the rooms on the Queen Mary, picking up items needed to rid the vessel of the final boss, Walter J Adamson, who is haunting Stateroom B340.")
    print("You are starting on the Top Deck and can select the commands: go North, go South, go East, or go West.")
    print("You have 6 items you must get in order to win, to add to inventory type 'get 'item name'")
    print("You may also exit the game at any point using the 'Quit' word.")
    print("Good luck!")
    print("_____________________________________________________________________________")
#to set up rooms
rooms = {'Top Deck': {'name': 'Top Deck', 'go south': 'Pool Room', 'go north': 'The Mauretania Room', 'go east': 'Hatch Door #13',
                        'text': 'You are on the Top Deck.', 'item': ''},
         'The Mauretania Room': {'name': 'The Mauretania Room', 'go east': 'Stateroom B340', 'go south': 'Top Deck', 'item': 'Priest',
                     'text': 'You entered The Mauretania Room.'},
         'Stateroom B340': {'name': 'Stateroom B340', 'go west': 'The Mauretania Room', 'item': 'Walter J Adamson',
                    'text': 'You entered Stateroom B340!'},
         'Pool Room': {'name': 'Pool Room', 'go west': 'Boiler Room #4', 'go north': 'Top Deck', 'go east': 'The Mayfair Room', 'item': 'Holy Robe',
                    'text': 'You entered the Pool Room.'},
         'Boiler Room #4': {'name': 'Boiler Room #4', 'go west': 'Pool Room', 'item': 'Holy Relic',
                    'text': 'You entered Boiler Room #4.'},
         'The Mayfair Room': {'name': 'The Mayfair Room', 'go west': 'Pool Room', 'item': 'Candles',
                    'text': 'You entered The Mayfair Room.'},
         'Hatch Door #13': {'name': 'Hatch Door #13', 'go west': 'Top Deck', 'go north': 'Bottom Deck', 'item': 'Salt',
                    'text': 'You entered Hatch Door #13.'},
         'Bottom Deck': {'name': 'Bottom Deck', 'go south': 'Hatch Door #13', 'item': 'Holy Bible',
                    'text': 'You entered the Bottom Deck.'}
}
#commands
directions = ['go north', 'go south', 'go east', 'go west']
instructions()
#to set up game loop and inventory

def main():
    current_room = 'Top Deck'
    inventory = []

    def show_status():
        print('')
        print(f'You are currently at the {current_room}')
        print(f'You currently have:', *inventory, sep='-')
        if rooms[current_room]['item'] == '' or rooms[current_room]['item'] in inventory:
            print('There are no items here.')
        else:
            print(f'There is a ' + rooms[current_room]['item'])
                    
    while True:
        show_status()
        if current_room == 'Stateroom B340':
            if len(inventory) != 7:
                print("GAME OVER -  Walter J Adamson has possessed you!\U0001F47B")
                break
            else:
                print("*Ghost Noises* \U0001F47B You have successfully rid the Queen Mary of Walter J Adamson’s ghost! Thank you for playing!")
                break
        
        command = input('\nPlease enter a direction or take an item: \n').strip().lower()
        current_item = rooms[current_room]['item']

        if command in directions:
            if command not in rooms[current_room]:
                print("Sorry, you can't go that way, please try again.")
            else:
                current_room = rooms[current_room][command]                
        elif command == 'quit':
            print('Bye!')
            break
        elif command == 'pick up {}'.format(current_item.lower()):
            if current_item not in inventory:
                print('You picked up the ' + current_item, 'and added it to your inventory.')
                inventory.append(current_item)
            elif current_item in inventory:
                print('You already have this item, do something else.')
            else:
                print('There is no item here.')
        else:
            print("That doesn't make sense, please try again.")

main()
```

Example run:

```
_____________________________________________________________________________
Welcome to the Queen Mary!
[...]
You are currently at the Top Deck
You currently have:
There are no items here.

Please enter a direction or take an item: 
go north

You are currently at the The Mauretania Room
You currently have:
There is a Priest

Please enter a direction or take an item: 
pick up priest
You picked up the Priest and added it to your inventory.

You are currently at the The Mauretania Room
You currently have:-Priest
There are no items here.

Please enter a direction or take an item: 
go east

You are currently at the Stateroom B340
You currently have:-Priest
There is a Walter J Adamson
GAME OVER -  Walter J Adamson has possessed you!
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver! Thank you so so so much! Was about to start throwing stuff o_o'